# Не отображается страница github.io

Tags: git, github, http-status-code-404

Подскажите. Создал репозиторий `site.github.io`, скачал себе.
Создал `index.html` и залил обратно.

```
PS D:\SITE\site.github.io> git add .
PS D:\SITE\site.github.io> git commit -m 'add files'
[master (root-commit) 9d7864d] add files
 1 file changed, 7 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 index.html
PS D:\SITE\site.github.io> git push
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 314 bytes | 314.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To https://github.com/dim04ka/site.github.io.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
PS D:\SITE\site.github.io>
```

`github.com/dim04ka/site.github.io` не отображается в браузере.
 Выдает ошибку:  **404**

Comment: У меня открывается.

Comment: @Эникейщик адесс https://dim04ka.github.io/site ?

Comment: Нет, тот адрес, который указан в вопросе - github.com/dim04ka/site.github.io

Comment: Дмитрий вы в settings все сделали правильно? Я имею ввиду там установлена master?

Comment: @VladSpirin master branch
Use the master branch for GitHub Pages. Я похоже напутал, открывается по адресу dim04ka.github.io/site.github.io/

Comment: Вижу у вас в репозиториях `landing-page-one.guthub.oi` и сомневаюсь, что там должно быть именно `oi`

Comment: Гитхаб не даст использовать вам домен, отличный от вашего ника — то есть только dim04ka.github.io. Чтобы что-нибудь открывалось по адресу https://dim04ka.github.io, вам нужно создать репозиторий, который так и будет называться `dim04ka.github.io` (если я правильно понял документацию гитхаба)

Answer (score 2):

согласно изложенному на [pages.github.com](https://pages.github.com/), вам надо создать хранилище (репозиторий) с именем `пользователь.github.io`.

именно так, [сначала ваше имя пользователя, затем `.github.io`](https://pages.github.com/images/user-repo@2x.png):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]